# Eliminar datos repetidos con distinta fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

quiero eliminar unos datos que me salen repetidos pero con distinta fecha, borrar el de la fecha mas vieja

tengo este pequeño ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cree este query para identificar las que tienen el CIF repetido, cuantas veces esta repetido y que me extraiga la fecha menor de esos repetidos

```
SELECT ui.CIF, COUNT(*) AS ClienIDRepetido , MIN(ui.FechaCambioEstado) AS UltimaFechaTransaccion  
FROM dbo.UIF06_AltasBajasClientes ui
WHERE ui.FechaReporteDatos='20210731'
GROUP BY ui.CIF
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

El cual me da el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces quiero eliminar esos registros que tengan repetido el CIF y con la fecha menor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la ayuda de una CTE para encontrar todos los datos que se repitan y dejar solo el último. A pesar de que parece que eliminamos de la CTE, realmente se eliminan de la tabla que la genera.

```
WITH cteUIF06 AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ui.CIF ORDER BY ui.FechaCambioEstado DESC) rn
    FROM dbo.UIF06_AltasBajasClientes ui
    WHERE ui.FechaReporteDatos = '20210731'
)
DELETE FROM cteUIF06
WHERE rn > 1;
```